# How can I shorten this jquery code

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn jquery from online tutorials. Following code is working for me but how can I shorten and improve this code? [this can be viewed on bottom of this page](http://www.neec.edu.pk/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#alltiles > div").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass("tile1");
        $(this).removeClass("tile");
        $('img', this).addClass("tileimg1");
        $('img', this).removeClass("tileimg");
        $('p', this).addClass("tilep1");
        $('p', this).removeClass("tilep");
    });
    $("#alltiles > div").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).addClass("tile");
        $(this).removeClass("tile1");
        $('img', this).addClass("tileimg");
        $('img', this).removeClass("tileimg1");
        $('p', this).addClass("tilep");
        $('p', this).removeClass("tilep1");
    });
});
```

Comment: You can achieve this using CSS alone with the `:hover` pseudo selector. It's better practice to do it this way as it is a better separation of concerns and also faster as the graphical effects of CSS are hardware accelerated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) on `hover` :

```
$(function() {
    $("#alltiles > div").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("tile","tile1");
        $('img', this).toggleClass("tileimg","tileimg1");
        $('p', this).toggleClass("tilep","tilep1");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [CSS styles](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) only :) 
Here are a lot of action which can be declared in 
This is the shortest solution.